# Error A non well formed numeric value con valores numéricos

Tags: php

Me está dando ese error en algunos casos y no acabo de entender el motivo. Los valores que recibe la función son numéricos. De hecho los valores se reciben de un array de 20 elementos y me falla en 6 cuando es el mismo formato en todos ellos.

El código es este:

```
echo "esto es divisa: " . $$divisa; //me devuelve el valor 0.0146264
echo "esto es la multiplicación: " . $posts[0]["$pais"] * $$divisa; // me devuelve 7.2985736
if (number_format($posts[0]["$pais"] * $$divisa,2,'.','') == $valor_minimo) { //PRIMER ERROR
   echo "<p class='menor'>" . number_format($posts[0]["$pais"] * $$divisa,2,'.','') . " " . $moneda_a_mostrar . "</p>";
} else {
   echo "<p class='mitad2'>" . number_format($posts[0]["$pais"] * $$divisa,2,'.','') . " " . $moneda_a_mostrar . "</p>"; //SEGUNDO ERROR
}
```

Lo que no entiendo es cómo puede ser que me marque error pero me esté haciendo bien los cálculos.

Comment: Pero te marca exactamente donde es el errror?

Comment: @LuisFernando Perdón, he editado la pregunta y he añadido donde se da el error. La primera es en la condicional if, que no entra porque me da el error comentado y el segundo se da dentro del else, que falla por el mismo motivo.

Comment: que version de PHP tienes?

Comment: creo que esta la estas usando mal, **number_format($posts[0]["$pais"] * $$divisa,2,'.','')** o que formato le quieres dar?

Comment: @LuisFernando ¿Cómo puedo saber la versión de PHP que tengo? En la web funciona bien, pero en local no. El formato es de un número con dos decimales.

Comment: solo haz un phpinfo()       `<?php 
phpinfo();
 ?>` si funciona en web puede ser que tengas desactualizado tu php

Comment: @LuisFernando Acabo de mirarlo, estoy usando PHP 7.1.8. En la web no me da problemas, en Mac tampoco...no sé porqué me lo está dando en Windows.

Comment: Acaso seran las comillas simples que tienes alli?

Comment: @LuisFernando No, acabo de probar y me sigue pasando lo mismo. No tiene tampoco sentido porque en los otros casos me funciona.

Comment: Quizá necesites usar _type casting_ en tus valores, como indica **[esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6542441/5587982)**. Está indicada para números `float`, pero puedes usar el _type casting_ que convenga en cada caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¡En el clavo! ¡Gracias!